# Are these prepared statement are correct

Tags: php, pdo

Am new to `PDO` and am a Freelancer, learning PHP

and finally after some research here is my code

```
<?php 
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "user");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "123456789");
define('DB_DATABASE', "test");
define('DB_DRIVER', "mysql");

$country = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country');
$capital = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'capital');
$language = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'language');

try {
    $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ":dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";host=" . DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO countries(name, capital, language) VALUES (:country, :capital, :language)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':capital', $capital, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':language', $language, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

    if($stmt->execute()) {
      echo '1 row has been inserted';  
    }

    $db = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    trigger_error('Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

?>
```

are these statement correct
above code is are prepared statement correct
because i get ERROR

> Fatal error: Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'name' inconnu dans field list in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AA WYSIWYG\PDO prepared stament.php on line 28

Comment: have you tried it? questions like "does this work?" are off-topic.

Comment: Are you getting any error if yes then its not working mate

Comment: @Uchiha its not working i get this error `Fatal error: Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'name' inconnu dans field list in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AA WYSIWYG\PDO prepared stament.php on line 28`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i get this error

Comment: Try `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL)` and check what errors are you getting

Comment: place errors in your question and not in comments please, thank you

Comment: @Uchiha added above code next to `<?php` i don't get anthing

Comment: Your error itself depicts that column not found `name` check your db, do you have that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(name, capital, language) VALUES (:country, :capital, :language)`

The error is clear, the `name` column does not exist.

> Fatal error: Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'name' inconnu dans field list in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AA WYSIWYG\PDO prepared stament.php on line 28

You may have meant to use `country`, seeing what the first value is in your VALUES.

- Verify and double check all your column names in your table.
- Only you know what the column names are.

Also make sure that all variables populate correctly, your form is using a post method and that all elements contain the name attribute.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: thats were i corrected and it works, does above code are proper prepare statement..? will it protect injection..?

Comment: @sanojlawrence Yes, that is how prepared statements work and you should be pretty good to go. You may also want to look up and research on XSS injection.